# Why is dynamicaly allocated array's size upon insertion 2*size of the initial array, rather than size+1?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, vector

I am a college Computer Science student and I have been trying to understand the stl::vector on a deeper level. I found out, vector are in fact dynamic arrays, meaning upon insertion/deletion, if needed, the array is resized.

A friend told me, when the array's reallocated, for example upon insertion, instead of creating a new array of size [original+1], it creates a new array of a size [2*original].

Wouldn't it be better to only add (or substract) one array field when you insert/delete something, instead of creating an array twice as large, leaving many indexes unused?

I thought the reason for this is, that perhaps creating an array twice as large, or reallocatin the array, only every once in a while rather than on every insertion/deletion has much better time complexcity, but for example, if I had an array of large objects, would it even then be still better to reallocate an array twice the size of original, or use size+1?

Thank you for responses.

Comment: Yes, it's because then array insertion is amortized `O(1)`. If you reallocated and potentially copied the whole array each time, then array insertion would be `O(n)`.

Comment: This post is very misleading. It's only specifically `std::vector` that reallocates in this way, not "any dynamically allocated array". In fact, `std::vector` is *not* a dynamically allocated array, and it separates memory from object construction, which makes this whole approach feasible in the first place.

Comment: @timrau Wow, thank you for the link, mate. I was trying all sorts of querries but couldn't ask the right question to see an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is mathematics.

Containers with the reallocation strategy that you describe (or *any* exponential growth, for that matter, the factor is irrelevant) guarantee *asymptotically averaged constant cost* for inserting an element at the end, i.e. the cost of inserting *n* elements, all divided by *n*, converges to a constant value as *n* gets large. That's because allocations get increasingly rare as *n* grows.

If you always grew the array by one on each insertion, you would incur linear cost for each insertion.

Note that `std::vector` is not a "dynamically allocated array" in the sense of C++'s native array type `new T[N]`; and instead it separates memory allocation from object construction. What grows exponentially is `std::vector`'s allocated memory. The number of constructed objects is always precisely the current size of the container.